# Proof $\log(cn)$ is in $\Theta(\log(n))$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

How can I prove that $\log(cn)$ is in $\Theta(\log(n))$, where $c$ is a constant? I tried to prove $c_1\log(n) \le \log(cn) \le c_2\log(n)$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are also constants, but I'm having trouble with that approach.

Comment: Hint: $\log(cn)=\log(c)+\log(n)$.

Comment: Can you explain a little further?

Comment: It depends how you define big theta, and what tools you have. The quick way is to note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log c+\log n}{\log n}=1$. Or else if $n$ is big enough, we have $\log n\gt \log c$, so $\log c+\log n\lt 2\log n$. For the other inequality, you can show that if $n$ is big enough, $\log c+\log n\gt (1/2)\log n$.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!

Comment: The false comment should be deleted.